# blog subsite giving 404 on accessing in public facing

Tags: 2010, 404

I need help and it would be great if anyone suggest/help.

The Problem is:

We added a blog sub-site in a SharePoint 2010 publishing site. now the site is browseable in the authoring version. But it is showing 404 on the public facing, the URL is

http://www.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/default.aspx

I am not seeing the publishing tab in authoring.

Do you have any idea how to make the blog site available in the public facing. Well appreciated for help.

Regards,
Zohaib

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have an Alternate Access Mapping set up for www.nextdocs.com and IIS has a binding for the host header.

I've seen similar behaviour when a web has been created without the host header and IIS has been used to bind the address to the site but SharePoint has no knowledge of the host header.